# axios - how to deal with big integers

Tags: javascript, axios, bigint

Here is my request:

```
    axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
```

The output is `{ value: 156144277082605255 }`

But should be `{ value: 156144277082605250 }`

How to deal with Big Integers in this case?
I tried to use [json-bigint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint)
But since I am getting response.data from axios as object - it doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My colleague answered the question:

I had to transform my response.data into string. 
(you may wonder - why the useless function - just to redefine default behavior, which parses string into object with JSON.parse - in here we skip this step)

```
axios.get(url, { transformResponse: [data  => data] });
```

and then parse with json-bigint

```
JSONBigInt.parse(res.data);
```

Comment: Also, depending on your problem you might want require JSONbig like so: `const JSONbig = require('json-bigint')({'storeAsString': true})`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answers, how to integrate JSONbigint with axios request and response interceptors.

```
import JSONbigint from 'json-bigint'
...

// request interceptor, preventing the response the default behaviour of parsing the response with JSON.parse
axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  request.transformResponse = [data => data]
  return request
})

// response interceptor parsing the response data with JSONbigint, and returning the response
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  response.data = JSONbigint.parse(response.data)
  return response
}
```

Integers that are within the range will remain of type `number` and those exceeding the range will be of type `BigNumber`. One could additionally parse `BigNumber` to `string` if required by simply calling `toString()` on the keys of type `BigNumber`

Answer (score 1):

Run this to install json-bigint: `npm install json-bigint --save`

Then, use the **transformResponse** as an option of the **axios** get request

```
const jsonBig = require('json-bigint');

let url = 'https://your-api';
axios.get(url, { transformResponse: function(response) {
      return jsonBig().parse(response.data);
}});
```

You can also use this in the following way:

```
const jsonBig = require('json-bigint');

axios({
  url: 'https://your-api',
  method: 'get',
  transformResponse: function(response) {
    return jsonBig().parse(response);
  },
})
```